# Recursive calculation and transposing results for date range in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 10 years of data (kf below) in the below format, I am trying to sum data for each month for each department. A snapshot of data from April 2023(in Example below) should give me sale_1 as sum of sale_amt in Apr 2023, sale_2 as sum of sale_amt in 1 month prior or March 2023 and so on. For no values I populate null.
To create a master table from this 10 year data I use the below PySpark code 10 times for 10 years but I am confused on how to transpose or vertically stack the calculations so that if someone queries my result they can get snapshots acccording to the month and year they filter on.(in Example). Any suggestions on doing this more efficiently in PySpark? TIA!

```
kf=main file with 10 years data
mf=kf.dropDuplicates(['dept_ID'])
gf=kf
month_list={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'}
window = Winddow().partitionBy("dept_ID")
for i in month_list:
   df = gf.filter(gf.month==i).withColumn("sale_"+i, sum(coalesce('sale_amt'), lit(0))).over(window))
   df = df.dropDuplicates(['dept_ID'])
   mf = mf.join(df, mf.dept_ID==df.dept_ID, 'left').drop(df.dept_ID)
```

```
kf:

dept_ID sale_amt    sale_date   sale_month  sale_year
1   10  4/1/2023    4   2023
1   60  4/1/2023    4   2023
1   30  3/1/2023    3   2023
1   15  3/1/2023    3   2023
1   12  2/1/2023    2   2023
1   10  1/1/2023    1   2023
1   90  1/1/2023    1   2023
1   40  12/1/2022   12  2022
1   40  11/1/2022   11  2022
1   75  10/1/2022   10  2022
1   30  9/1/2022    9   2022
1   50  9/1/2022    9   2022
1   25  8/1/2022    8   2022
1   40  8/1/2022    8   2022
1   70  7/1/2022    7   2022
1   80  5/1/2022    5   2022
1   10  5/1/2022    5   2022
1   45  4/1/2022    4   2022
1   15  4/1/2022    4   2022
2   10  4/1/2023    4   2023
2   60  4/1/2023    4   2023
2   30  3/1/2023    3   2023
2   15  3/1/2023    3   2023
2   12  2/1/2023    2   2023
2   10  1/1/2023    1   2023
2   90  1/1/2023    1   2023
2   40  12/1/2022   12  2023
2   40  11/1/2022   11  2023
2   80  10/1/2022   10  2023
2   30  9/1/2022    9   2023
3   50  9/1/2022    9   2023
3   25  8/1/2022    8   2023
3   40  8/1/2022    8   2023
3   70  7/1/2022    7   2023
3   80  5/1/2022    5   2023
3   10  5/1/2022    5   2023
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: can you share the data in text format..

Comment: Yes, done…………..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another spark-sql solution.

Assuming that OP wants the snapshot for 12 month backwards for a given year_month_number as the input.

A reference view is created with null amt values for all the yearmonth combinations from year starting 2010 to 2025 i.e 12*15.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("sale.csv")
val df2=df.withColumn("dt2",to_date(col("sale_date"),"MM/dd/yy"))
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("sale")

val ref_df = spark.sql(" select add_months('2010-01-01',id) yyyymm, cast(null as decimal(15,3)) amt from range(12*15)  order by 1 ")
ref_df.createOrReplaceTempView("ref")

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true") // to allow cross join 
// Inputs
val year_month=202304
val month=year_month.toString.drop(4)
val year=year_month.toString.take(4)
val yearp=year.toInt-1
val dfs = spark.sql(s""" with t1 (select dept_id, date_format(dt2,'yyyyMM') yyyymm,  sum(sale_amt) sale_amt 
                                            from sale where year(dt2) in (${year},${yearp}) group by 1,2
                                   union all 
                                    select dept_id, date_format(yyyymm,'yyyyMM') yyyymm, amt from ref , (select distinct(dept_id) dept_id from sale) where year(yyyymm) in (${year},${yearp})
                                 )
 select dept_id, yyyymm, sale_amt amt from t1 
 where months_between(to_date('${year_month}01','yyyyMMdd'),to_date(yyyymm||'01','yyyyMMdd')) < 12
 and   months_between(to_date('${year_month}01','yyyyMMdd'),to_date(yyyymm||'01','yyyyMMdd')) >= 0   
""")

dfs.show(50,false)

dfs.createOrReplaceTempView("sale2")

val vl_ym = spark.sql("select collect_set(yyyymm) from sale2").as[Seq[String]].first.map( x => "'"+x+"'").sorted.reverse.mkString(",")
val dfs2 = spark.sql(s"""
select * from (select dept_id, yyyymm, sum(amt) amt from sale2 group by 1,2 ) t
 PIVOT ( 
  sum(amt) as amt
  FOR yyyymm IN ( ${vl_ym} )
  ) 
""")

dfs2.withColumn("year",lit(year)).withColumn("month",lit(month)).orderBy("dept_id").show(false)
```

The last output being

```
+-------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+-----+
|dept_id|202304|202303|202302|202301 |202212|202211|202210|202209|202208|202207|202206|202205|year|month|
+-------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+-----+
|1      |70.000|45.000|12.000|100.000|40.000|40.000|75.000|80.000|65.000|70.000|null  |90.000|2023|04   |
|2      |70.000|45.000|12.000|100.000|40.000|40.000|80.000|30.000|null  |null  |null  |null  |2023|04   |
|3      |null  |null  |null  |null   |null  |null  |null  |50.000|65.000|70.000|null  |90.000|2023|04   |
+-------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+-----+
```

You can rename 202304,202303.. to sale_1, sale_2.. etc

Pyspark part for the concatenated string:

```
>>> seqString=spark.sql("select array_sort(collect_set(yyyymm)) from ( select date_format(add_months(date'2023-01-01',id),'yyyyMM') yyyymm from range(12)) ").collect()[0][0]
>>> sorted_seq = sorted(seqString, reverse=True)
>>> addPrefix=''.join(map(lambda x: "'" + x + "'",sorted_seq))
>>> addPrefix
"'202312''202311''202310''202309''202308''202307''202306''202305''202304''202303''202302''202301'"
>>>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. My use case has a very huge dataset so the cross - join is very costly.

Comment: No, the cross join is only for the distinct dept ids.. so if 100 dept ids, then you will have 100*12*15 records as onetime activity.. should not be a big deal

Comment: Can we replace sequence of strings syntax with something else like tuple?
```.as[Seq[String]]```

Comment: the "FOR" clause of pivot expects them in single quoted a,b,c => 'a','b','c'  so even if you convert it to tuple, you should construct in this way when passing into it

Comment: I am able to get it in the correct format but somehow unable to use in the query dfs2 ```vl_ym = spark.sql("select collect_set(yyyymm) from sale2") 
firstRow = vl_ym.head()
seqString = firstRow[0]
sorted_seq = sorted(seqString, reverse=True)
addPrefix = udf(lambda x: "'" + x + "'" )
transformedseq = [addPrefix(x) for x in sorted_seq]
result = ",".join(sortedSeq)
vl_ym=result```

Comment: oh.. you are looking for python solution.. let me try that part

Comment: upadted the answer.. you need to use ````collect()[0][0]````

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple pivot problem.

```
year = '2023'
month = '04'

df.withColumn('is_current', f.expr(f'if(sale_year = {year} and sale_month = {month}, true, false)')) \
  .withColumn('order', f.expr(f'if(sale_year = {year} and sale_month = {month}, 1, dense_rank() over (partition by dept_ID, is_current order by sale_year desc, sale_month desc) + 1)')) \
  .filter('order <= 12') \
  .withColumn('col_name', f.concat(f.lit('sale_'), f.col('order'))) \
  .groupBy('dept_ID') \
  .pivot('col_name') \
  .agg(f.sum('sale_amt')) \
  .withColumn('year', f.lit(year)) \
  .withColumn('month', f.lit(month)) \
  .show()

+-------+------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+-----+
|dept_ID|sale_1|sale_10|sale_12|sale_2|sale_3|sale_4|sale_5|sale_6|sale_7|sale_8|sale_9|year|month|
+-------+------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+-----+
|      1|    70|     70|     90|    45|    12|   100|    40|    40|    75|    80|    65|2023|   04|
+-------+------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi Lamanus, thanks for the solution, it partially works. I am trying to run a loop on year '2023' & month Jan-Dec. When year='2023' & month='01', order variable goes negative hence I am getting sale_amt_-1, sale_amt_-2. Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: you can use a window and use dense_rank function.

Comment: When I use dense_rank, all the variables are being calculated as same for all dept ID. 01 is for Jan, 02 for Feb and so on.

Comment: So, what is your required column order?

Comment: So column order is fine. But if month=3, sale_1 should be the March sum of sale_amt, currently for each month from 1 to 12 sale_1 is January sale.

Comment: then check the current and split the partition again that makes the sale_1 column always indicate the current.

Comment: After the above edit, sale_1 is correct! Sale amount sum in month Dec is populated in sale_2, Nov in sale_3 and so on. Ideally should be, April sum of amount in sale_1 (which is right), March sale amount in sale_2, Feb in sale_3, Jan in sale_4, and so on.

Comment: Also, in your initial solution - date was being considered. But lets say if Mar 2022 to Mar 2023 data is available. and year=2023, month=03. Then sale_4 will not have Dec 2022 data.